# Using "find" in csh script file

Tags: unix, csh, tcsh

I run a .csh file in UNIX that contains the following script

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
set path = "$1"
find "$path" -name myfolder
```

And get the following message

```
find: Command not found.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$path` variable is special - it tells the shell where to find tools like `find`. :-)  Use a different variable name.

From your interactive shell, you can see what `$path` normally looks like by echoing it. The following is my path on my FreeBSD server:

```
ghoti% echo $path
/usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /home/ghoti/bin /usr/X11R6/bin /usr/games
```

If this list is replaced with something else, for example the contents of `$1`, then tcsh doesn't know to look in `/usr/bin` to find `find`:

```
ghoti% which find
/usr/bin/find
ghoti% set path = "hello world"
ghoti% which find
find: Command not found.
ghoti%
```

Comment: @yagev, we're all entitled to one of these every once in a while. But now you've met your quota....  ;-)